# Hash() function is not working in wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a payment gateway but I am unable to hash the string.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Payment
 *
 * @link    https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Mitech
 * @since   1.0
 */

get_header();
?>
<?php 
$email = $_GET['email'];
$Price = $_GET['asdcsa'];



// How to calculate request signature.
$shaString  = '';
// array request
$arrData    = array(
'command'            =>'AUTHORIZATION',
'access_code' => 'WboNsNukQq6CpM5sFTb6',
'merchant_identifier' => 'oZCzyQtx',
'merchant_reference' => 'XYZ9239-yu898',
'amount'             =>'10000',
'currency'           =>'AED',
'language'           =>'en',
'customer_email'     =>'test@payfort.com',
'order_description'  =>'iPhone 6-S',
);
// sort an array by key
ksort($arrData);
foreach ($arrData as $key => $value) {
    $shaString .= "$key=$value";
}
// make sure to fill your sha request pass phrase.
$shaString = "$2y$10$XPu7h2ekY" . $shaString . "$2y$10$XPu7h2ekY";
$signature = hash("SHA-256", $shaString);


echo $signature;
```

Here is the code which I have used to convert the string into a hash.

Here is the link of the page https://saudibulksms.com/en/payment/

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

use ' instead of ", otherwise it will try to resolve the strings as variables, like

`$shaString = '$2y$10$XPu7h2ekY' . $shaString . '$2y$10$XPu7h2ekY';`

In addition the correct parameter for the `hash()` method is `"sha256"` and not SHA-256 as far as i saw in the documentation.

Edit:
Additionally to avoid duplication mistakes and to make the code more readable i would suggest to use a variable for `'$2y$10$XPu7h2ekY'`